# How to model bind using a complex model with Nancy and razor

Tags: razor, nancy

Is there a way to model bind using a complex model with Nancy and the razor viewengine?

I'm passing a viewmodel to the view:

```cs
public class EditViewModel
    {
        public Presentation Presentation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which contains the Presentation class:

```cs
public class Presentation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the view I have a form. This is how I would have set it up in an MVC app, the name & ID attributes matching up with the Presentation object's fields. I'm aware that I can't retrieve using Request.Form with the . in the name.

```
<form class="@Url.Content("~/presentation/edit/" + @Model.Presentation.Id)" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Presentation.Title" id="Presentation_Title" placeholder="Title" value="@Model.Presentation.Title">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

My module handles the post like so:

```cs
Post["/edit/{id}"] = _ =>
{
    EditViewModel model = this.Bind<EditViewModel>();

    return View["edit", model];
};
```

The model is always null.

The only way I've managed to get this to work is to duplicate the Presentation` class' fields and map them against a new instance of Presentation. Is this the preferred/recommended way to handle data within viewmodels?

I can't pass the Presentation class directly to the view because I have proxy creation enabled in EF which throws an error.